# Why can I call a non-static function by a static pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, static

I thought I cannot use a static pointer to call a non-static function, since I think a static pointer belongs to the whole class but non-static function belongs to a specific object.  But somehow I made it succeed and am not sure why this is so.

Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdio>

class B
{
public:
    void show(int aValue);
};

//B.cpp
void B::show(int aValue)
{
    if (aValue == 100)
        printf("This is the desired value");
    else
        printf("This is not the desired value");
}

class A
{
private:
    static B* mUpdater;
public:
    static int function1();
};

B* A::mUpdater = new B();
int A::function1()
{
    int final = 100;
    mUpdater->show(final); // mUpdater is a static pointer, show is a non-static function
    return 1;
}


int main()
{
    return !A::function1();
}
```

The code runs, and prints "This is the desired value". But I am a little bit confused since I thought the code cannot run.  Is this because I assign the address of a specific object to the pointer so that It can work? Or no matter in which case, static pointer can just call non-static functions?

Any idea will be more than appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more complete definitions of classes A and B.

Comment: The fact that `mUpdater` is `static` allows you to use `A::mUpdater` without an instance of `A`. Its usage afterward is identical.

Comment: In your example you don't call the show function of class A, but of mUpdater which is a pointer to an object of type B. Your question cannot be answered properly without a clear definition of class B.

Comment: well i had to remove two comments because I was a bit confused, please make it an MCVE. At the moment it is rather unclear. Does `A` inherit from `B` ?

Comment: I believe that your misunderstanding is that you "cannot use a static pointer to call a non-static function".  What you can't do is call a non-static function if you don't have any object at all to call it "with" (that is, doing `show(1);` inside `function1` won't work). As long as you have a valid object, how or where that object is stored doesn't matter.

Comment: @molbdnilo This should be in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Let's assume that `B` inherits from `A` (see the comments to your question).)

A `static` member function means you cannot use the `this` pointer of the class/object.  In `A::function1()` you do not use the `this`-pointer. Instead you call a function, which may or may not be static, of an actual instance (of `B`). It does not matter whether you access that instance via a static/non-static pointer/reference. Thus your usage is valid.

However, your code is quite confusing. Your `show()` function does not use any variables of the class anyway, so it might as well be static. Also it seems implausible that you use a pointer to another object of type `B` to call a non-static member function from a static member function of `A`. You might end up in a situation in which data of some instance of `B` is used when you expect data of some instance of `A` to be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I just simplified the code and I just wanna show the structure. Actually there are some other arguments in show function. I don't know why you think that B inherits from A, actually they are of no inherit relationship

Comment: Oh I know...Sorry I made a mistake, `show()` is of class B, I will modify my codes

Answer (score 1):

> I thought I cannot use a static pointer to call a non-static function, since I think a static pointer belongs to the whole class but non-static function belongs to a specific object.

The static member pointer belongs to the "whole" class, and so all instances (or other static member functions) can access it. But once they access it, they're accessing nothing more than a pointer.

And specifically, if the pointer is to an instance of that same class, then those functions can also access private members of the object pointed to by that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are asking about

```
static B* mUpdater;
```

Specifically, you are surprised that

```
mUpdater->show(final);
```

is legal C++.

It's important to understand that the `static` keyword above refers to `mUpdater`, not what it points to.  That is, there's a pointer, shared by all `A` that points to a single *object* of class `B`.

When you write `mUpdater->show()`, that dereferences `A::mUpdater` to access the single `B` object, and calls the `show()` method of that `B`.

You can simplify your example further, which makes it easier to pick out your question from the distractions around it:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct B
{
    void show() {
        printf("This is B::show()\n");
    }
};

struct A
{
    static B *worker;
    static void f() {
        worker->show();
    }
};

B* A::worker = new B();


int main()
{
    A::f();
    return 0;
}
```